# Ruby, sketchup-add another textbox to the unput box

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I am running this code through the ruby sketchup console.

```
            prompts = ["Stair Width", "Travel","Tread Thickness","Total Height","Riser Thickness","Stringer Width","Stringer Thickness","Top Hanger Thickness","Customer","Customer Address","Top Hanger Nose","Stair Nose","Flight"]
    defaults = [36.0,0.00,1.0,0.00,0.5,11.25,1.25,0.5,"My Builder", "234 Jimmys Street","Yes","Yes","Main"]
    list=["","","","","","","","","","", "Yes|No","Yes|No"]

    input = UI.inputbox prompts, defaults,list, "Stair Info"
        a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m=input
        cst=i.to_s
        adr=j.to_s
ent = Sketchup.active_model.entities
    tr=(d/8.0).ceil
    rise=d/tr
    run=((b-(1+h))/(tr-1))
```

I would like to add an additional textbox beside the "Total Height" input box and make it equal tr when exiting the "Total Height" input box.
Is there a way to add a textbox beside the Total Height input box and have it equal "tr" once leaving the Total Height input box?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the layout you need to create your own dialog. `UI.inputbox` doesn't give any control over this.

The other Ruby alternative for this in SketchUp is to use `UI::HtmlDialog` (from SketchUp 2017 and up; http://ruby.sketchup.com/UI/HtmlDialog.html) It uses an embedded Chromium control. If you need to support older versions of SketchUp you can use `UI::WebDialog`; http://ruby.sketchup.com/UI/WebDialog.html. `UI::WebDialog` uses the system browser available (IE on Windows, Safari/WebKit on Mac). You cannot be sure what version the user have installed though.

Some useful info about WebDialog can be found here: https://github.com/thomthom/sketchup-webdialogs-the-lost-manual/wiki

You can also try the SKUI project, it is a wrapper on top of WebDialog which let you create simple UI widgets using only Ruby code: https://github.com/thomthom/SKUI (It abstracts away the HTML/CSS code)